# How to create an array containing only inf with a specific shape?

Tags: python-3.x, matlab, numpy

Here is a Matlab vector: `a = [inf(m,1);ones(m,1)]`

I tried to create a similar object in a python way.

I tried this:

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.stack((np.tile(np.array([np.inf]), (m, 0))),np.ones((m,0)))
```

by testing this in the console with changing `m` for `5` for example and trying to view it with PyCharm, I got this message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2019.1.3\helpers\pydev\_pydev_comm\server.py", line 34, in handle
    self.processor.process(iprot, oprot)
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2019.1.3\helpers\third_party\thriftpy\_shaded_thriftpy\thrift.py", line 266, in process
    self.handle_exception(e, result)
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2019.1.3\helpers\third_party\thriftpy\_shaded_thriftpy\thrift.py", line 254, in handle_exception
    raise e
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2019.1.3\helpers\third_party\thriftpy\_shaded_thriftpy\thrift.py", line 263, in process
    result.success = call()
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2019.1.3\helpers\third_party\thriftpy\_shaded_thriftpy\thrift.py", line 228, in call
    return f(*(args.__dict__[k] for k in api_args))
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2019.1.3\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_console_utils.py", line 359, in getArray
    return pydevd_thrift.table_like_struct_to_thrift_struct(array, name, roffset, coffset, rows, cols, format)
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2019.1.3\helpers\pydev\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_thrift.py", line 602, in table_like_struct_to_thrift_struct
    return TYPE_TO_THRIFT_STRUCT_CONVERTERS[type_name](array, name, roffset, coffset, rows, cols, format)
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2019.1.3\helpers\pydev\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_thrift.py", line 377, in array_to_thrift_struct
    array, array_chunk, r, c, f = array_to_meta_thrift_struct(array, name, format)
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2019.1.3\helpers\pydev\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_thrift.py", line 476, in array_to_meta_thrift_struct
    bounds = (array.min(), array.max())
  File "C:\Users\Azerty\PycharmProjects\OptionsHedgeFund\venv37\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_methods.py", line 32, in _amin
    return umr_minimum(a, axis, None, out, keepdims, initial)
ValueError: zero-size array to reduction operation minimum which has no identity
```

What's wrong with it?

Comment: For people unfamiliar with matlab.... what `a = [inf(m,1);ones(m,1)]` does?

Comment: that how we create matrices in Matlab, always between brackets ```[x,y,z;a,b,c]``` and to to specify the rows we use ```;```
This would return in Python : ```([x,y,z]n\ [a,b,c])```

Comment: So are you trying to create a m x 2 matrix whose first row is made by infinites and second row made by ones?

Comment: You probably want to replace the zeros with ones and also move one closing parenthesis to the very right and use `concatenate` instead of `stack`

Comment: My bad, i guess i got it wrong.. i am sure now that the matlab code generates m rows of inf and then add starting from the next of the last of inf row, m rows of one

Comment: You could use `1/(np.c_[:2*m]//m)` or the more pedestrian and healthier `np.repeat([[np.inf],[1]],m,0)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In an Octave session:

```
>> m = 5;
>> a = [inf(m,1); ones(m,1)];
>> size(a)
ans =

   10    1

>> a
a =

   Inf
   Inf
   Inf
   Inf
   Inf
     1
     1
     1
     1
     1
```

In a `ipython` session:

```
In [21]: m=5                                                                                                 
In [22]: np.vstack([np.ones((m,1))*np.inf, np.ones((m,1))])                                                  
Out[22]: 
array([[inf],
       [inf],
       [inf],
       [inf],
       [inf],
       [ 1.],
       [ 1.],
       [ 1.],
       [ 1.],
       [ 1.]])
In [23]: _.shape                                                                                             
Out[23]: (10, 1)
```

A variation that does the same thing:`

```
np.concatenate([np.full((m,1), np.inf), np.ones((m,1))], axis=0)
```

===

For two rows, start with (1,m) shapes:

```
>> a = [inf(1,m); ones(1,m)];
>> size(a)
ans =

   2   5

>> a
a =

   Inf   Inf   Inf   Inf   Inf
     1     1     1     1     1

In [26]: np.concatenate([np.full((1,m), np.inf), np.ones((1,m))], axis=0)                                    
Out[26]: 
array([[inf, inf, inf, inf, inf],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.]])
```

===

As for your error, `np.stack` is having problems joining two (5,0) shaped arrays (I'm not entirely sure why).

```
In [27]: a = np.stack((np.tile(np.array([np.inf]), (m, 0))),np.ones((m,0)))                                  
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-27-c6f8ec8462c9> in <module>
----> 1 a = np.stack((np.tile(np.array([np.inf]), (m, 0))),np.ones((m,0)))

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/core/shape_base.py in stack(arrays, axis, out)
    417 
    418     result_ndim = arrays[0].ndim + 1
--> 419     axis = normalize_axis_index(axis, result_ndim)
    420 
    421     sl = (slice(None),) * axis + (_nx.newaxis,)

TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

Your error was different; looks like it was produced by `pydev`, not Python itself.

But check the pieces:

```
In [28]: np.tile(np.array([np.inf]), (m, 0))                                                                 
Out[28]: array([], shape=(5, 0), dtype=float64)
In [29]: np.ones((m,0))                                                                                      
Out[29]: array([], shape=(5, 0), dtype=float64)

In [31]: a = np.vstack([(np.tile(np.array([np.inf]), (m, 0))),np.ones((m,0))])                               
In [32]: a                                                                                                   
Out[32]: array([], shape=(10, 0), dtype=float64)
```

Replace the (m,0) with (m,1) and we get the desired (10,1) array:

```
In [33]: a = np.vstack([(np.tile(np.array([np.inf]), (m, 1))),np.ones((m,1))])
```

`stack` adds a dimension - which is not what you want:

```
In [35]: a = np.stack([(np.tile(np.array([np.inf]), (m, 1))),np.ones((m,1))])                                
In [36]: a.shape                                                                                             
Out[36]: (2, 5, 1)
```

Though with a simple start shape, we get 2 rows:

```
In [37]: a = np.stack([(np.tile(np.array([np.inf]), (m,))),np.ones((m))])                                    
In [38]: a.shape                                                                                             
Out[38]: (2, 5)
```

Actually the problem with your `stack` was a misplace `)`.  Here's the correct one:

```
In [50]: np.stack((np.tile(np.array([np.inf]), (m, 0)),np.ones((m,0))))                                      
Out[50]: array([], shape=(2, 5, 0), dtype=float64)
```

Your closing ) was after the `tile`, so the `np.ones()` expression was in the `axis` parameter position.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I found why the ```np.stack``` returns an error. It's because of ```np.ones``` and ```np.zeros```. I have to assign ```1``` in the column index ```np.zeros((m,1))``` , ```np.ones((m,1))```

Answer (score 2):

So if I understood correctly your expected result, you may do like this to generate your matrix.

```
m = 5 #or whatever

a = np.ones((2, m)) #create a matrix 2 x m of ones
a[0] = np.inf #replace first row with infinites
```

`a` is:

```
array([[inf, inf, inf, inf, inf],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Numpy has functions dedicated to filling arrays. See 'full()', 'fill()'.

```
a = np.full((2, 2), np.inf)
array([[inf, inf],
       [inf, inf]])
```